# why i am getting error "(1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''")" in python 3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, tkinter

i am making a gui using tkinter and python, in the project i want insert and update the data base but after putting the values i am getting this warning and my database is not updated

```
    name=username.get()
    acc=ask.get()
    pi=val.get()
    am=nw.get()

    conn = connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db='atm')
    var = conn.cursor()
    var.execute("select * from account_detail where 
    account_no='"+acc+"'and pin='"+pi+"' ")
    row=var.rowcount
    if(row>0):
        var.execute("update account_detail set amount=amount+'"+am+"' 
        where account='"+acc+"' ")
        var.execute("insert into mini (account_no,pin,username,balance) 
        values ('"+acc+"','"+pi+"','"+name+"','"+am+"' ) ")
        conn.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Information","deposited  successfully")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Information","not valid")
        conn.rollback()
        messagebox.showinfo("Information","Data Transfer Failed")

updatebtn=Button(upwin,text="deposit",font="Times 10",relief=RAISED,bd=8,command=depo,width=20).place(x=130,y=230)
```

getting this error

Warning (from warnings module):File"C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170
    result = self._query(query)
Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''")

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the amount value before the sum operation.

```
update account_detail set amount= isnull(amount,0) + '"+am+"'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but nothing happened, its showing me the same error